# Any possible reasons, when cannot create web application at sharepoint 2007 from central administration or using extendvs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Pls give me any suggestion.

Now I cannot create new web applicaion at sharepoint 2007 from central administration ... error shows that "unknow error" ... so any possible reasons?? ... that i need to check for this error ...

I also cannot create new web application with extendvs stsadm command ... because my database server is from the another machine  .. errors shows that ...

Directory lookup for the file "F:\MSSQL\DATA\WSS_Content_Internet_NewProd.mdf" f
ailed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specifie
d.).
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check relat
ed errors.

CREATE DATABASE failed at stsadm -o extendvs

so ... any things that i need to check ??

I have appropritate permission to use the database from another machine ...

pls give me any suggestion to create new web application using central admin or extendvs

any possible reasons ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a database, any database, manually on that SQL server, you will probably get an error as well. This could be a result of misconfiguration on the server or physical errors on disk F.

Comment: now i create "MSSQL\DATA" ... and then create web application from central administration ... now can create web application ... but i do not see my website 8082 in the iis and virtualdirectory ... can i do any possible way without running "iisreset /noforce" ? because we can do "iisreset/noforce" at the midnight because other services are running on the server from other vendors.. thanks a lot ...

Comment: Have you created the site in the new database?